# How can I convert SUM to MAX in all rows in excel?

Tags: excel, sum, max, formula, rows

I have a column with around 2000 rows with with a SUM formula and differentes ranges. For example:

```
=SUM(H2:H7)
=SUM(H8:H11)
=SUM(H12:H15)
...
```

What I need is:

```
=MAX(C2:C7)
=MAX(C8:C11)
=MAX(C12:C15)
...
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to:

1. Select the entire area with content that you wanna replace
2. Open the `find & replace` module
3. Search for: `SUM` and replace with `MAX`
4. Search for: `H` and replace with `C`

Done.